# How to choose and validate interdisciplinary research methodology?

Tags: methodology, interdisciplinary

How to formalize the following research consideration towards research methodology selection and validation?

That is, I consider to establish and validate interdisciplinary foundations for a discipline A using foundations of discipline B, and formally validate if it makes sense.

Hypothesis: is it possible to model, analyze and solve problems regarding end to end software application lifecycle management (aka DevOps) based on foundations of system engineering, specifically logistics engineering?

Example case study: assess component flow from positions of optimization methods for material flow.

Now which methodology is in place to proceed with evaluation and validation of the hypothesis so that findings would be broader than just "I used method X of 10 possible for a specific software application of myriad possible and it was a 13% gain, maybe due to some luck or an error in the whole setup or my bias"?

That is practical experiments would validate research, but after gathering practical experiences in a series of projects I am looking first towards creating theoretical and analytical foundations in this direction to design more large scale experiments and have some scientific output as well.

In case this is an existing field of interdisciplinary research to your knowledge please point to it as well in your answer.